# How do you pass a string as an option in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using **Discord.js V13 (Node JS v16.8.0)** and wanted to pass a string as an option

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('punish')
        .setDescription('Punish a Guild Member')
          .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('target')
              .setDescription('Select a user')
              .setRequired(true))

          .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('category')
              .setDescription('Choose punishment')
              .setRequired(true)
              .addChoice('Kick', 'kick')
              .addChoice('Ban', 'ban')),

async execute(interaction) {
  const member = interaction.options.getMember('target');
  const type = interaction.options.getString('type')
  
  await member.type(`Reason: Spam`) //member.ban() / member.kick()
  await interaction.reply("Kicked member successfully.")

  },
};
```

I've got the user's selection *(category)* and would like to execute a punishment in accordance with it.

When I execute `member.type()` I of course get an error since I can not pass a string as an option, Is there any way I could possibly do this?

I know you can do `if (type == 'kick') { //... } if (type == 'ban') { //... }` but I think my solution is more convenient and useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a property of `member` by its name (and call its methods) like this:

```js
member["propertyName"]();
```

So in your use case:

```js
member[type]('Reason: Spam');
```